# How would an atom look like if we knew where the electrons were? (I know it’s silly)

Tags: wavefunction, electrons, atoms, superposition

So we have the normal depictions of atoms, a nucleus made of spherical protons and neutrons, and orbiting spherical electrons, them we have the fuzzy blob depictions, where there is a center, and then there is a gigantoc blob around it, or rainbow donuts, i understand because of the wave function, the blob depictions are  more accurate, in that there is a probability of where an electron will be. But what if we knew where the electrons were? Would it be the orbiting electrons around nucleus, or something totally different?

Comment: From MinutePhysics, [A Better Way To Picture Atoms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2Xb2GFK2yc)

Comment: What does it mean to look like? At the end our eyes is also a captor giving us some signal

Comment: What would an atom be like if electrons enjoyed classical music but didn't like jazz?  I know that this question is silly, as you know that yours is.  But I think there is insight to be gained from the recognition that both questions are **equally** silly and in exactly the same ways and for exactly the same reasons.   It is just not in the nature of an electron to have a musical preference, and it is just as much not in the nature of an electron to have a location.  If it had either a musical preference or a location, it would be nothing at all like an electron.

Comment: @WillO. I don't think that's really correct. You can measure the location of an electron to arbitrary precision, so saying it doesn't have a location (position) because it is an electron is questionable at best.

Answer (score 2):

You would not be able to "see" an electron in an atom. Like a black hole it is invisible until it chooses to emit a photon. If you are lucky and you absorb that photon you would be able to make a 'guess' at its energy. We can only see an images when we absorb hundreds or thousands of photons so seeing a single "passive" atom with light is not really possible.

You would be able to detect the atom as you got closer as it's electric/magnetic fields generate Van der Waals forces.

The size of an atom is dictated by Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle - roughly speaking the energy (and hence momentum) of the electron generates the uncertainty that causes the electron to be "smeared" out as an electron cloud. If you want to decrease that uncertainty and make a much more precise positional measurement, you will impart momentum (and hence energy) to the electron and it will cease to be bound to the atom. The atom will become an ion.

If you did somehow measure the position of an electron in an atom with some arbitrarily high precision (say with another electron or an proton), then it would have no implications regarding what the electron was doing before the measurement as Bell's Inequality suggests that it did not even have a well defined location before your measurement. (Note: Some proponents of non-standard Quantum interpretation may argue with this - please don't down vote just for this)

Answer (score 1):

If you measured the position of the electron orbiting its nucleus, it would just be a dot in the vicinity of the nucleus. However you would not be able to "see if it's orbiting or doing something totally different" because you would not be able to tell its momentum/velocity. The [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) dictates that we cannot possibly simultaneously measure position and momentum to arbitrary precision. (because their corresponding quantum operators do not commute)

So if you measure $(x,y,z)$ of the electron, you will have infinite uncertainty on its momentum $(p_x,p_y,p_z)$ and therefore you cannot describe its motion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one can create an atomic state as a more or less localised electron by making a superposition of different atomic wave functions $\Psi=\sum_n C_n\psi_n(\vec{r})\text{e}^{-\text{i}E_n}t$, and this localised electron will "rotate" around the nucleus, but for not so long time because the atom will radiate photons and the coefficients $C_n$ will be time dependent: $C_n=C_n(t)$, so in the end you will finish with an atom in the ground state.